# Moodle: PDFs are empty

Tags: moodle

Many PDFs from different courses appear to have been corrupted or something. We first noticed when viewing to view in CHrome and got the error "Failed to load PDF document." In Internet Explorer the page just shows up empty. 
When viewing the file in the "Updating file in" area, it says the following: "Either the file does not exist or there is a permission problem." It has a file size, but when I click on Download, the file is 0 kb.

Where are the files saved? Why are they corrupted?

Update: I've narrowed it down to that the /moodledate/filedir lost all the references. The folders are there as well as the files. Is there any way to fix this without having to reupload all PDFs?

I am on version 3.6.3 on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content/path hash is stored in the `mdl_files` table - maybe have a look in there to see if you can match up the files. The hash should match the folder/file name.

```
SELECT *
FROM mdl_files
WHERE filename LIKE '%pdf%'
OR mimetype LIKE '%pdf%'
OR source LIKE '%pdf%'
```

Also, check the file permissions. I don't use Windows, so not sure how it works on there. But on Linux, the web server should have access to the data folder.

Something like:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /pathto/moodledata/
sudo chmod -R 02777 /pathto/moodledata/
```

see https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Security_recommendations#Most_secure.2Fparanoid_file_permissions

Comment: When I was trying to delete sessions I ended up deleting the whole moodledata folder a while back ago and didn't realize this is where the files were. I managed to restore it, but there are a few orphan files. I installed the File trash plugin and now I have a few orphan files. After restoring the folders and files I had entries in the database, but no files.